# Designing database structure for multiple prices per shop

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps

My app has a simple interface that when a button is clicked, it displays a Google Map screen with 5 markers. When these markers are clicked, a popup window appears that displays prices of a shop, for example:

```
Food:  £1
Water: £2
```

I am trying to implement a database with my application, so I can store multiple prices of only Food and Water, nothing else. For example -

Shop A has Food and Water which prices can vary from £1 - £10 and Shop B also has Food and Water, which prices can vary from £1 - £10 like Shop A's.

How can I design a table that has Shop A as a row, with 10 different prices as columns, and another row called Shop B that also contains 10 different prices? 
Would it make sense to do something like the following -

```
Shop A | FoodPrice_1 | WaterPrice_1 | FoodPrice_2 | WaterPrice_2 | FoodPrice_3
Tesco  | 1.99        | 2.05         | 1.04        | 2.31         | 1.93

Shop B    | FoodPrice_1 | WaterPrice_1 | FoodPrice_2 | WaterPrice_2 | FoodPrice_3
Sainsburys| 1.99        | 2.05         | 1.04        | 2.31         | 1.93
```

Would it be possible to iterate through each column and display the prices to a certain marker?

This doesn't have to be a completely perfect design by the way, the app won't be published. The main thing that I want to do is to be able to display each price separately, so a complex structure isn't needed.

Comment: You seem to have it backwards. If you have ten different prices, you should have ten different _rows_ in the table, not ten columns.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy How is it backwards? I was thinking of the way I have it above so I could just do a query like - `SELECT FoodPrice_1, WaterPrice_1 FROM Shops WHERE Shop_Name = 'Shop A'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example I would assume the name of the column would be the brand of the product? You don't want that.It's not modulare at all.

You might want a tables that look like this instead :

A shop table with 2 columns:

```
id | shop_name
```

A product_list table with 4 columns:

```
id | shop_id  | product_id | product_price
```

A product table with

```
id | product_name | other_attributes
```

Or even a Shop table with 2 columns:

```
id | shop_name
```

A product table with

```
id | product_name | product_price | shop_id
```

So it all depends on your needs.

In your case and if the app doesn't evolve you might want to use the 2nd option as long as there isn't a lot of duplicate data it won't be an issue.

In general I wouldn't go for the second one since the exact same shop might sale the same product as another with the only difference being the price so you might not want to have duplicate product_name or attributes ( weigth,size, color, ... ) , imagine if 5 shop sell the exact same products (I'll add additional info to make it look more obvious) your db would like like this :

```
id | product_name | product_price | shop_id | product_weigth | product_flavor

id | Coca-Cola    | product_price | 1       | 2L             | Cherry
id | Coca-Cola    | product_price | 2       | 2L             | Cherry
id | Coca-Cola    | product_price | 3       | 2L             | Cherry
id | Coca-Cola    | product_price | 4       | 2L             | Cherry
```

But with solution one you would have

A product_list table with 3 columns

```
id | shop_id  | product_id | product_price
1  | 1        | 1          | product_price
2  | 2        | 1          | product_price
3  | 3        | 1          | product_price
```

A product table with

```
id | product_name | Weight | Flavor
1  | Coca-Cola    | 2l     | Cherry
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No in my example, the name of the column would be where `Shop A` is and the price of the product is where it says `FoodPrice_1` So it would be `Shop A | 1.99` for example. It is ok if both shops have the exact same price for the same item also. The reason I thought my way would be ok was that I could easily query `Shop A` for each of the prices

Comment: maybe i expressed myself poorly but i mean how do you know what product is waterprice_1 ? If your example isn't :
`Shop A | Water_type1_price | Water_type2_Price ` , I don't understand how can you tell the difference between water1 and water2.The collumn has to represent a difference between the two no?

TBH i dont really get your question anymore :)

Comment: Yeah sorry looking back on my question now, it isn't too clear what I was trying to explain. The table headers would be `Shop A | WaterPrice_1 | FoodPrice_1 |` And underneath `WaterPrice_1` would be the price, I'll update my original question to see if it makes it more clearer.

Comment: Nah that part was quite clear :
`Shop A | WaterPrice_1 | FoodPrice_1 | WaterPrice_2`

`Wallmart | 10   | 43 | 40`

I mean yeah if you really only have a few type of product that are always the same you can do 
` id | shop name | product_1_price | product_2_price`  and guess that collumn 3 = water and collumn 4 = cheese in your app.  I would still name those collumn bread_price and cheese_price.
What's confusing in your example is that you have 2 times water_price

Comment: Sorry Jay, I updated my question to try make it clearer what I mean. In my table there is only two products, in this case, Food and Water, and these two products prices can vary for example from £1 up to £10, I want to store each of these prices from £1-£10 in a table, and iterate through these prices, and send one (depending on what column is selected) to a TextView in my Google Maps. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Hum ok it seems a bit clearer yes. So on your map the marker is the Shop location right ? so when user click the marker the information displayed is the price of the products , but how do you choose which price to select in the case of  `Tesco  | 1.99        | 2.05         | 1.04        | 2.31         | 1.93`   ?
Cause i'm assuming that you would display only TWO price out of that list right ( since there is 3 food price and 2 water price) ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I can only display two prices out of the list. In my head, I have it imagined that when the map first loads, it queries the database for say `FoodPrice_1` and `WaterPrice_1` and displays the information, and I want to have a refresh button, that when it is pressed, it will query `FoodPrice_2` and `WaterPrice_2` if that makes sense? Here is how I have my markers defined - 

`Double foodPrice = 1.8;
Double waterPrice = 1.2

mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarkers("Tesco", "tesco", Double.parseDouble("1.111"), Double.parseDouble("-1.111"), "Food: €" + foodPrice, "Water: €" + waterPrice));`

Comment: So you want to track the evolution of the price of products and always display the most up to date price while still keeping the older ones ? What about displaying them ? Refreshing only display the most recent ones right?
In that case i'd probably  create a product table as stated before that would look like 

`id | product_name | product_price | shop_id | timestamp`

and then query sql with `max(timestamp)`

Comment: Not necessarily the most up to date price, I just want to be able to cycle through the columns when a refresh button is pressed, and send the data of whatever column I am on to a marker. Eg, on first load, the marker displays the data corresponding to the columns `FoodPrice_1` and `WaterPrice_1`, and when the refresh button is selected, it will display the data corresponding to `FoodPrice_2` and `WaterPrice_2` and so on. I am not inputting any data to this database, I am only taking data from it.

Comment: Well ok, so honestly it's not really DB design anymore cause one design or the other isn't going to change anything, it's really only a java issue and i'm not good at java so i can't really help you here. 
I'm guessing you should look into loading all your data to your view when the user click on the pin. 
Then display only part of it and iterate on click. I wouldn't try to get the data back from the db every time. But i'm not even sure thats how you do things in java. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help. The hardest part I think will be trying to iterate through the columns and display the values in Google Maps. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create two tables:
`Shop(#shop_id, shop_name);`
and
`Product(product_id, product_name, product_price, (ref) shop_id);`
Do not forget to add check constraint to product_name (`check product_name in {'Food', 'Water'};`).
Now you can add as many rows as you want in the Product table that represents a product, its price and what shop it belongs two.